# Lisp - Utilisation of comma (`,`) in macro

Tags: macros, lisp, elisp

I am practising writing macros in Elisp. The teacher suggested us to include the macro part of the program in "quasiquote".

I would like to write a macro "printCdrEach" that print each element of cdr of the list (Just for the sake of practicing)

```
(defmacro print-cdr-each (first &rest rest)
  `(while (not (null ,rest))
    (eval (car ,rest))
     (setq rest (cdr ,rest)))
  )

(print-cdr-each 1 2 3 4) ; Expected Output 2 3 4
```

I keep getting the error "Invalid function: 2". I am sure that the compiler thought `2` is a function. However, I am not sure how to fix this program.

Without changing the input format `(printCdrEach x x x x)` , what is the appropriate use of "," in my program in order for it to work?

Comment: Why is this a macro? The first rule of macro-writing is: don't write one when a function will suffice. Possibly the second rule is: don't use `eval` unless you have to, and you probably don't. Also, prefer `kebab-case` to `camelCase` in lisps: lispers care ;)

Comment: Yes that is why I say that it is just for practising the syntax since I am new to Lisp, so I want to start something easy.  And it is noted, I didn't know this naming convention in Lisp. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Also, if I don't use `eval` how would I print out the element here? (The `car` of `rest`) Is the source of the error coming from the fact that I use `eval`?

Comment: (2 3 4) will be in place of ,rest, so (car ,rest) will evaluate to 2, and (eval 2) does not work because 2 is not a function, hence the error message. Would you not want to use a function that prints in place of the eval?

Comment: `eval` isn't for printing things, it is for evaluating forms. Macros are for code transformations, not for executing arbitrary code. An easy solution, not using a macro, would be: `(defun print-cdr-each (&rest xs) (format t "~{~A~^ ~}~%" xs))`.

Comment: @JayK -- `(eval 2)` works fine, because `eval` evaluates forms. It is just the wrong thing to do. `(car ,rest)` --> `(car (2 3 4))`, and `(2 3 4)` attempts to call a function `2` with the arguments `3` and `4`. Instead, `(car (quote ,rest))` might be a step in the right direction.

Comment: @adabsurdum True that. Too long ago that I used Lisp apparently.

Comment: @adabsurdum Thanks a lot. Just as I said, such macro wouldn't be necessary but it is good to know that `(quote)` exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try `macroexpand-1`:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(print-cdr-each 1 2 3 4))
; ==> (while (not (null (2 3 4))) 
;       (eval (car (2 3 4))) 
;       (setq rest (cdr (2 3 4)))) 
; ==> t
```

- Expression `(2 3 4)` is invalid. Try it in the REPL and you get `eval: 1 is not a function name`
- You are using `rest` several times so if it was an expression it would be evaluated more than once.

There is really no need for a macro:

```
(defun for-each (operation &rest elements)
  (loop :for e :in elements
        :do (funcall operation e)))

(for-each #'print 10 20)
10
20
; ==> nil
```

Macros are syntax sugar. That means you should be able to say what
`(print-cdr-each 1 2 3 4)` should expand to in code. Since you are doing it as a macro you may want to expand it to static:

```
(defmacro for-each (operation &rest elements)
  `(progn ,@(loop :for e :in elements 
                  :collect `(,operation ,e))))

(macroexpand-1 '(for-each print a b))
; ==> (progn (print a) (print b))
; ==> t

(let ((a 10) (b 20)) (for-each print a b))
10
20
; ==> 20
```

Comment: The question is based on elisp, while I think your answer is CL. Elisp does have `while`.  Not sure if there is fancy `loop` though (I bet there is a package...).